# Wpf DataTrigger unexplained behavior

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Here is a bunch of triggers. The problem is that if i place the last trigger first      `<DataTrigger Value="True">`  then it **wont even go into converter** if other match. Why does this happen ? Does WPF not follow the declared order but tries to optimise ? Because if I leave empty setters then it never gets into converter.

```
 <DataTemplate.Triggers>





                    <DataTrigger Value="0">
                        <DataTrigger.Binding>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource tableOrderConvertor}">
                                <Binding Path="."></Binding>
                                <Binding ElementName="control" Path="DataContext.ActiveOrders"></Binding>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TableFullBrush}" TargetName="table"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#2DFF5A" TargetName="tableName"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#346902" TargetName="table"/>
                    </DataTrigger>




                    <DataTrigger Value="1">
                        <DataTrigger.Binding>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource tableOrderConvertor}">
                                <Binding Path="."></Binding>
                                <Binding ElementName="control" Path="DataContext.ActiveOrders"></Binding>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TableFullBrush}" TargetName="table"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#F79644" TargetName="tableName"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#346902" TargetName="table"/>
                    </DataTrigger>

                    <DataTrigger Value="2">
                        <DataTrigger.Binding>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource tableOrderConvertor}">
                                <Binding Path="."></Binding>
                                <Binding ElementName="control" Path="DataContext.ActiveOrders"></Binding>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TableFullBrush}" TargetName="table"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#16D4FF" TargetName="tableName"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#346902" TargetName="table"/>
                    </DataTrigger>


                    <DataTrigger Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.Binding>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource tableOwnerConvertor}">
                                <Binding Path="."></Binding>
                                <Binding ElementName="control" Path="DataContext.ActiveOrders"></Binding>
                                <Binding ElementName="control" Path="DataContext.SelectedShift"></Binding>
                            </MultiBinding>


                        </DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" TargetName="table"/>

                    </DataTrigger>


                    <!-- trigga gia my table -->

                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: That is just odd to see integers and True.  What is the output type of tableOwnerConvertor?

Comment: boolean there are two convertors

Comment: I missed the two converters.  It would help if you would fix the formatting.